# How to generate a combination of cells in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I want to generate a cell with a combination of data I've insterted in specific cells in LibreOffice. Can anyone comment?

This is what I'm after ( I'd like a slash in between the data):

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMDo8.png)

Comment: It would have been better to give the example in the question's text instead of linking to an image.

Answer (score 0):

From the image, it looks like "Input 1" is in A2 and "Input 4" is in D2. So, use the following formula to get "Input 4 / Input 1".

```
=D2 & " / " & A2
```

Comment: `=CONCATENATE()`